# What is "Gatcha" short for?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations, pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations

What is *gatcha* short for? Is it standard English, or is it used in the spoken language only?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an English native, but shouldn't it be "gOtcha"?

Comment: Can you give the context where you saw or heard this? A quote is best.

Comment: @AgustiRoig Almost certainly, unless it's referring to [Gatchaman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Ninja_Team_Gatchaman)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've got you!

I imagine it was derived like this:

I've got you! → Got you! → Got ya! → Gotcha! → Gatcha!

Answer (score 3):

[**Gotcha**] [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha)

*Gotcha* and *I gotcha* are relaxed pronunciations of "I['ve] got you", usually referring to an unexpected capture or discovery. Gotcha is a common colloquialism meaning to understand or comprehend.

It is the reduced written form of *got you* = *got* +‎ *-cha*

Gotcha can also be spelled as *gotchya* whereas the related term, *getcha*, is made by joining the verb and pronoun, *get you*, with *-cha*.

There are no *written* instances of "gatcha".

My guess is that the OP has heard the [Blondie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFerLNdpwO4) song, "One Way or Another" recently covered by the British boy band, *One Direction* and mixed "gotcha" with "getcha". :)

```
One way, or another, I’m gonna find ya
I’m gonna getcha getcha getcha getcha
One way, or another, I’m gonna win ya
I’m gonna getcha getcha getcha getcha

One way or another, I’m gonna see ya
I’m gonna meetcha meetcha meetcha meetcha
One day, maybe next week
I’m gonna meetcha, I’m gonna meetcha, I’ll meetcha

I will, drive past your house
And if, the lights are all out
I’ll see who’s around
Let's Go!
```

Repeat